# How to assign a bytes object to a NumPy array slice?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, byte

I want to use NumPy arrays to efficiently operate on large byte arrays. Unfortunately, assigning a `bytes` object to a slice of the NumPy array does not work as I would expect:

```py
import struct
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.uint8)

# Store 65535 into the first two bytes
array[0:2] = struct.pack('<H', 65535)            # does not work

print(array)
```

This leads to the following exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In this example, the `bytes` object results from a call to `struct.pack`. When wrapping the result into a `bytearray`, everything works as intended, but I think this will perform an unnecessary copy operation (which is not what I want):

```
array[0:2] = bytearray(struct.pack('<H', 65535)) # works
```

Why does a `bytes` object not work here? The fact that `bytearray` is mutable whereas `bytes` is not should not make a difference here.

I'm using NumPy version 1.16.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) which references the underlying buffer. This should avoid creating a copy.

```
array[:2] = memoryview(struct.pack('<H', 65535))
array
# array([255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0], dtype=uint8)
```

It seems you cannot assign a byte string directly as NumPy attempts to decode the bytes into characters according to an encoding scheme (which would explain the `UnicodeDecodeError`) before assignment. With a `bytearray` or `memoryview`, it is implied that each byte is separate.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) both `bytes` and `bytearray` do support the buffer protocol. So there must be some other difference, maybe it is the `numpy` implementation itself?

Comment: @ph4nt0m Only speculating here, I think the reason is that if you pass a byte string v/s a bytearray, numpy will try to decode the former according to a character encoding scheme. Whereas in a bytearray, the bytes are interpreted separately. Just my guess.